# What does this callback() function do?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, jquery-select2

I'm looking at integrating Select2 with Knockout ([see here](https://github.com/ivaynberg/select2/wiki/Knockout.js-Integration)). There is a small section of the code that I do not understand:

```
success: function (data) {
                query.callback({
                    results: data
                });
            }
```

What does that `callback()` function do? It takes in the response/result as a parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As described in http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/ (search for "query(options)" on that page to find the relevant section), callback is a function that should be called with the result object.

So when the user has done a search, and you have done a lookup of the results from somewhere (ajax call or whatever), you need to bring that data back to select2. This is done through the callback.